# Run ASP.NET site from TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, .net, selenium, teamcity

I need to run ASP.NET site for UI tests with selenium web driver from TeamCity. It is possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

Teamcity is not an application host, it is merely a web UI to what is effectively a scheduler.

You need to create a script that can automatically deploy your software onto an ASP.NET host somewhere. Depending on what you have now, that can be anything from an [xcopy deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9.aspx), to [remote running an MSI installer](http://quigleyweb.wordpress.com/2007/05/11/8/). There are many resources to help you do this.

After that, you can invoke selenium and point it at the site you just deployed.

Once you have the script, you can it to be invoked from your main build script, or you can add build steps in Teamcity, or you can create another project in Teamcity that has your main project as an [artifact dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Artifact+Dependencies). With a separate project, you can run the tests independently. This may be a good idea if the tests take a long time to run -- you can set them up to run nightly, and then you don't have a team constantly sitting around waiting for long-running tests to finish.

Be sure to use a site that is dedicated to this script / your CI build, so that nothing interferes with it while the tests are running.

Answer (score 1):

Tell team city to use a fixed working folder. Make that working folder a virtual directory of IIS. Have your tests point at the URL that goes with that virtual directory you created.

Be warned, you'll probably have file locking issues where IIS has files locked and team city is trying to delete and recompile them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you can write a nant script that executes your Unittests. I did a post on the topic some time back that might be helpful to you.  http://kristjansson.us/?p=947